# Qt EnumProcess - unresolved external

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, linker

I'm trying to compile a Qt app with the following pro file:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2012-12-26T16:41:05
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = AutoROP
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

LIBS += "D:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.1/Lib/Psapi.Lib"
```

I also included the windows.h and psapi.h header files in my code and tried to call EnumProcess (I'm in a win32 environment) but I'm receiving "unresolved external symbol EnumProcess referenced in .."
and I can't solve it. I tried with -lpsapi, I tried inverting forward and back slashes.. nothing worked.

Where am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with pragma directives.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Excuse me sir, which author? Nobody answered me and I solved the problem myself.